# How to disable Bootstrap on an element?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to disable the Bootstrap styles on my image and hr, but when I try to add `class="list-unstyled"` nothing changes. I have even tried using it on a div, but no luck there.

```
<div class="list-unstyled">
    <img src=images/logo.png alt="logo" height="54" wdth="133" class="list-unstyled">
    <hr class="list-unstyled">
</div>
```

Comment: You don't think that maybe `list-unstyled` is designed to be used on lists?

Answer (score 0):

```
.list-unstyled
```

Removes the default list-style and left margin on list items (works on both `<ul>` and `<ol>`). This class only applies to immediate children list items (to remove the default list-style from any nested lists, apply this class to any nested lists as well)

For more detailed about **.list-unstyled**
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#unstyled

For your problem, you need to override this class or remove this class and apply your own class and then apply CSS styling.

Answer (score -1):

You need to override the css for the particular elements(where you don't want bootstrap default css). Also, class="list-unstyled" in not working here because it's used for disabling list-items styling.

Comment: How do I override them?

Comment: Use new class for the element and give styling in your own css file. Make sure you are including your css file after the bootstrap css file.